Python plot with doubled ticks
I've trying to plot some data in a subplot. Even If I define an empty array for ticks or I define labels, always appear a second tick markers in axes.
Here is my code:
    fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))
    ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
    fig2.subplots_adjust(left=0.07,right=1,top=1,bottom=0.07)
    canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=FrameDVH)
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(x=0,y=0)
    color=['green','red','blue','black','yellow','orange']
    try:
        for d in range(0,len(DVH_TPS[:,0,0])-1):
            ax2.plot(DVH_TPS[d,:,0],DVH_TPS[d,:,1],'-o', markersize=1,color=color[d])
    except Exception:
        pass
    
    ax2.set_yticks([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
    ax2.set_xticks([dosis*0.2,dosis*0.4,dosis*0.8,dosis,dosis*1.2])
    canvas2.draw()

This is a capture of my result plot:

Even when I define an empty array as ticks:
[

maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run.

You are creating two axes on top of each other with the very first lines:
fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))  # first axes
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)  # second axes on top of first one

The unused axes of the first line remains unused and causes those unwanted effects. A simple way to solve this would be to get rid of the second line in your code.
Here's a minimal example:

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# plt.subplots already creates an axes you can use
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
fig2.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=1, top=1, bottom=0.07)
colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'orange']
for d, color in zip(range(5), colors):
    ax2.plot([1 + d, 2 + d, -3 + d], color=color)
ax2.set_xticks([0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 1.2])
plt.show()


